# C#: Chart: fastest way to put data from received UDP packet

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, sockets, charts

I'm trying to write a simple UDP-to-Chart app (for windows forms) that will get raw data from ethernet, and put it in a specific way to a chart. Here's what i have so far: Form with two charts, a Thread to receive UDP packets:

```
public void serverThread()
    {
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(Convert.ToInt16(tbEthPort.Text));
        while (_serverWork)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt16(tbEthPort.Text));
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                if (receiveBytes.Length > 0)
                    for (i = 0; i < receiveBytes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        bigDataIn[i] = receiveBytes[i];
                    }
```

and draw second chart (that shows all packet contents in a specific way):

```
if (graphicOn)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        graphicData[i + (graphicStep * 32)] = bigDataIn[i * 32 + graphicChan];
    }
    graphicStep++;
    if (graphicStep == 32) graphicStep = 0; 
    try
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => { chartGraphic.Series["DataGraphic"].Points.DataBindXY(graphicEnum, graphicData);
        }));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

and a main thread with timer to draw first chart.

```
private void tmrHisto_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] slice = new int[32];
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            slice[i] = bigDataIn[i + 32 * histogramArrayStep];

        histogramArrayStep++;
        if (histogramArrayStep == 32) histogramArrayStep = 0;

        chartHistogram.Series["DataHistogram"].Points.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < HISTO_XMAX; i++)
        {
            chartHistogram.Series["DataHistogram"].Points.AddXY(i, slice[i]);
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, on my PC, and several others, but when I launch my app on old PC's, my app starts to loose packets. Packet loss starts when I begin to `Invoke` `chartGraphic`. I can see all packets (about 20 in a second) in WireShark without any losses. I experienced same problems, when timer interval was set to 50ms instead of 150ms, but I can't increase interval anymore.

So that's my question - can I increase the speed of graphic drawing, and stop packet losses on low-end PC's. Or how can I emulate low-end PC during debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Invoke` is blocking, so your receivethread will wait until the drawing *(DataBindXY)* is complete. Try to move it outside the receive thread.

A circular buffer looks fast, but it looks that it only holds references. This doesn't improve much. Besides, you are getting new buffers from the udpClient: `Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);` Circular buffers are only usefull when 'old' memory is reused.

Try a concurrent queue to pass data from the receive thread to the gui-thread/timer. Be sure that rebinding/drawing is outside the lock of the concurrent queue. Now you're getting performance to receive datagrams.

---

UPDATE:

Some **pseudo** code:

Back:

```
private List<byte[]> datagrams = new List<byte[]>();

public void serverThread()
{
    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(Convert.ToInt16(tbEthPort.Text));
    while (_serverWork)
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt16(tbEthPort.Text));
            Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

            // add to the queue
            lock (datagrams)
                datagrams.Add(receiveBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

GUI:

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();

public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[][] data;

    // lock the queue as short as possible. (create a copy with ToArray())
    // this way the receive thread can run again..
    // this is also know as bulk processing..
    lock (datagrams)
    {
        data = datagrams.ToArray();
        datagrams.Clear();
    }

    // if no packets received, don't update anything
    if(data.Length == 0)
        return;

    // process the received data (multiple datagrams)
    for(byte[] item in data)
    {
        ...
    }
    // Update chart
}
```

---

You might check if the queue doesn't grow too large. When this happens, your queue processing is too slow. You could limit the itemcount.

Comment: UDP receiver is taken from MSDN. I even tried to move drawing to other thread, but failed, cos of low C# experience I guess or maybe cos i used `Invoke` there as well... Will try to avoid invokes

Comment: I've added an example for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work fine for me, cos I need to update my `chartGraphic` every time I receive data, and `chartHistogram` by timer ticks...

Comment: You should not update the gui directly on receiving data. It will stall your receive actions. Your gui is much much slower than receiving data. So, if you don't want to mis any UDP, don't update the gui on the receiving thread.

Comment: I got it but can't figure out how to avoid it... I always developed FPGA so i guess i can't think in a C-way properly))) I tried to update GUI in separate thread, but it still uses `Invoke`, that is slowing me down again i guess

Comment: Like my example shows, one thread will fill the queue, the other thread _(gui thread with timer)_ will handle the packets/data. This way you never need to invoke. The queue is the medium to 'transfer' data from one thread to the other thread. This is the same way I handle my UPD packets _(robot positions, angles)_  from a PLC which are sent with an interval of 2ms.

Comment: So you say i can set the timer tick to a very small interval (almost invisible to a naked eye) for gui drawing and have no problem receiving packets and drawing GUI for hours of work?

Comment: Yep. You should set the Timer interval to something like 30ms for approximately 30 fps. You don't need to display 100 fps.. Ofcourse it always depends on the speed of the drawing routines, but if the drawing routes suck, none of the solutions will ever work. I'll modify my solution with a little upgrade.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123667/discussion-between-vanechka-and-jeroen-van-langen).